# How to fetch data from network and not from http cache?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2

Here is my code , I have added CacheHeaderInterceptor but one of the requests
for some cases  needs to do force call from network instead of retrieving cache response
but as I have added CacheHeaderInterceptor it never called after first call.
but I need to have check and based on that check fetch from network or retrieve cache response

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun httpClient(context: Context, @Named(“UserPreferences”) preferences: SharedPreferences): OkHttpClient {
val appCacheDir = context.cacheDir
val httpCacheDir = File(appCacheDir, HTTP_CACHE_DIRNAME)
if (!httpCacheDir.exists()) {
  httpCacheDir.mkdirs()
}
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
val authInterceptor = LegacyAuthInterceptor(preferences, userAuthRelay)
builder.addNetworkInterceptor(authInterceptor)

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  builder.addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
}

builder.addNetworkInterceptor(CacheHeaderInterceptor(isStoreUpdatedRelay))

return builder
    .cache(Cache(httpCacheDir, MAX_HTTP_CACHE_SIZE))
    .connectTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build()
  }

  class CacheHeaderInterceptor(private val isUpdatedRelay: BehaviorRelay<Boolean>) : Interceptor {



override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

chain.request().headers().get(CustomCacheHeader.CUSTOM_CACHE_HEADER_KEY)
    ?: return chain.proceed(chain.request()) 



val maxAge = chain.request().headers().values(CustomCacheHeader.CUSTOM_CACHE_HEADER_KEY).firstOrNull()?.toLongOrNull()

val modifiedRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().removeHeader(CustomCacheHeader.CUSTOM_CACHE_HEADER_KEY).build()

val originalResponse = chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
return when {
  isUpdatedRelay.value -> {
    val modifiedResponse = originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .build()
    isStoreUpdatedRelay.accept(false)
    modifiedResponse
  }
  maxAge != null -> {
    // Add Cache-Control to the response.
    val modifiedResponse = originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
        .removeHeader("Pragma")
        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=$maxAge")
        .build()
    modifiedResponse
  }
  else -> // Missing max-age, proceed with original response.
    originalResponse
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question
adding addInterceptor() 
There is addNetworkInterceptor() and addInterceptor().